# Sidecar HTTP/TCP health check process for nomad containers

Tags: docker, nomad

I have a docker image that runs a single process that doesn't bind any ports (dials out only). Trying to run this under nomad does not work because the nomad allocation scheduler expects *something* to be either GETable (http check) or at least TCP connectable (tcp check). The guarantee provided by the underlying image is that as long as the ENTRYPOINT command isn't crashed it's considered healthy.

Is there a lightweight way to expose some kind of endpoint/port to make nomad view the container as healthy? I was considering something like binding a port with netcat in the background as an extra layer but this does not feel very elegant.

Comment: If the base image doesn't provide a health check, you've no choice but to invent your own. However, I fail to see the benefit in that since anything you do won't necessarily prove the base image is doing its job. You say it provides a guarantee, but the whole point of health check is "trust, but verify". Perhaps you should think about what happens if you don't provide a health check. Is the container going to be killed?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar maybe I should have said "contract" rather than "guarantee" -- I understand that I am not going to get an accurate picture of the health of the process but actually checking that would be non-trivial with this process

I could perhaps specify on_update: ignore with a fake port and assume container exiting due to process crash would be the ultimate "check" but I'm actually not sure how that works